# A universal way of getting file and folder icons in Windows

Tags: winapi, dll, autohotkey

I am writing the AutoHotkey script and would like to display the contents of the directory along with the icons. 
Everything I found, says that getting icons requires the use of many different winapi functions to get icons for: folders, exe files, files associated with programs, etc.
Is there a DLL, winapi function or AuoHotkey library that has a universal interface for many file types?

Answer (score 6):

[`SHGetFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx) can extract a HICON and/or give you the system image list index of a path or PIDL.

Get a [`IExtractIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761854(v=vs.85).aspx) from a `IShellFolder` and use the `GIL_ASYNC` flag if you need to do the extraction on a background thread.